# What is the difference between lengthen and elongate in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

[image]

What is the difference between lengthen and elongate in this context (in 23)? 
According to the answer key, it is "lengthen". However, why can't we use elongate as well?

My research (these are the Cambridge Dictionary definitions):
[lengthen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lengthen)
[elongate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elongate)

I believe both can work in this context, however, the authors of this CAE trainer seem to disagree.

Comment: I think either could be used. Elongate is a bit more formal / academic perhaps, but they seem interchangeable in this context.

Comment: It's the sort of problem that should have been addressed by the editorial board. This sort of thing doesn't inspire confidence in the relevant authorities.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Bear in mind the *context*. The people doing the study might reasonably have simply decided to "standardise" on ***lengthen / widen***, for example, rather than have to deal with a range of alternatives such as ***elongate / broaden***. And let's not forget that it's nearly always *Why the long face?*, not *Why the elongated face?*

Comment: @FF The context is a test. I've a fair bit of experience with moderation. You'd mark 'elongate' wrong here? I distinctly hope that's not the case: 
check the Ngrams KarlG provides, and his good analysis.  And a marking scheme that doesn't include / cater for all correct answers is reprehensible. _They've slipped up_.

Comment: 'Lengthen' would be to add length, so adding substance to make the thing longer. 'Elongate' is to stretch out what is already there, adding no further substance.

Comment: Was this a fill-in-the-blank test (where you had to come up with the word), or a multiple-choice test (where you were supposed to pick the "best" among several choices)? If the former, they probably overlooked one possible synonym. If the latter, it was just a horrible question all around. Either way it was the fault of the testmakers, but a difference between sloppiness and gross incompetence.

Comment: @1006a Not to blame the setters. You have the answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words *lengthen* and *elongate* are characteristic of the way the English language may have two words with virtually identical meanings: one Germanic and the other Latinate, either directly from Latin or through French.

*Lengthen* [arose in the late 14th century](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lengthen) from adding the factitive -en suffix often used to transform adjectives into verbs (shorten, whiten, broaden, widen). Earlier speakers had simply used the adjective as a verb: *to length* (to brown meat,  to short an investment, to book a hotel room, to map the area).

*Elongate* first appears in the 1530s, as the [Online Etymological Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/elongate) explains, from Late Latin *elongatus*, p.p. of *elongare* ‘to prolong, protract, remove to a distance’. *Elongate* replaced the earlier borrowing *elongen*
(mid-15c.), formed with the same -en suffix as *lengthen*.

English speakers regulary apply both verbs to the human face:

> When styling a rounder face, your main goal is to [*elongate the face*](https://www.luxyhair.com/blogs/hair-blog/hairstyles-for-different-face-shapes) and make it appear more oval.
>
> To slim down and [*lengthen the face*](https://www.jeancoutu.com/en/beauty/beauty-tips/the-best-beard-style-for-your-face-shape/), opt for a beard that is relatively long at the chin and shorter on the cheeks.

Despite a [general preference for *lengthen*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elongate_VERB%2C+lengthen&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celongate_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clengthen%3B%2Cc0) over *elongate*, a [Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elongate+the+face%2Clengthen+the+face&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celongate%20the%20face%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clengthen%20the%20face%3B%2Cc0) shows that the frequency difference between the two verbs with the direct object *face* is now insignificant:

[image]

When the past participle is used attributively as an adjective, however, there is a [strong preference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=elongated+face%2Clengthened+face&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celongated%20face%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clengthened%20face%3B%2Cc0) for *elongated*:

[image]

This would suggest that the authors of the test simply didn't think of the word *elongate* as they were writing the question. There are, however, no grounds, either in meaning or usage, to consider *elongate* an error.

This does not mean that the two verbs are complete synonyms. *Elongate* is not often used in a temporal sense, for example, except in an elongated stay at a hotel. And a street is extended or lengthened. But with the human face, they are.

Comment: Yes. To the extent that [*elongate* implies *stretching*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/elongate) where [*lengthen* does not](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/lengthen), *elongate* is even arguably the more appropriate choice for the particular context.

Comment: Why elongate a short answer? See comment by @1006a .

Comment: @1006a That should have been the answer. (I am visiting this Q just now.)

Answer (score 0):

Lengthen and elongate differ (in usage) according to what it is that is being altered or extended in a certain way. To elongate suggests a stretching or alteration that is not part of a symmetrical or proportional change. Lengthen also may be contrasted to "widen," Whereas 'elongate' in English does not seem to have a counterpart in 'making wider' in some way. Faces may indeed be 'long,' but this is a verbal expression denoting a person's *facial* expression, for example, in the introduction to "The Flowers of St. Francis (of Assisi)" the writer suggests that they were not intended to be read "with the long face of piety." "Lengthen" also has both a physical and temporal connotation (lengthen in time as well as physical dimension) whereas elongate *typically* refers to physical measurements.